# Im trying to remove a string from an array after I use it. But i don't know where I'm going wrong

Tags: java, arrays

```
    for (int x = 0; x < arrays.length; x++) {


        for (int y = (x + 1); y < arrays.length; y++) {

            if (arrays[x].compareToIgnoreCase(arrays[y]) == 0) {

                String temp = arrays[x];
                arrays[x] = arrays[y];
                arrays[y] = temp;
                words=arrays[x];
                count++;
                arrays[y]= null;// I wanna remove arrays[y] from the array.
              }
          }
      }
```

I used the bubble sort to find and count the amount of duplicates in the array but when i print out the amount of duplicates in the array it gives me. For example.

```
Word: Car  Printed:3 times
Word: Car  Printed:2 times
Word: Car  Printed:1 times
```

Comment: So if the two strings are the same, you swap them? And then you delete one of them? May i ask what you are doing?

Comment: I'm reading a text in which I have to count how many times each word is used. This count should not be case-sensitive
and then print out all the words in alphabetical order in ‘proper’ case (that is: first letter capitalized and lower case throughout the rest of the word) along with the number of times that word has appeared in the text.
Each word should only be printed once.

Comment: @F.Lachlan If you are still not satisfied with the answers and comments, you can add your own comments and ask for more. Otherwise, validate an answer to close this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not removing anything: you are just setting null reference in the Array. You should use an `ArrayList`instead. This will do the work, with its method `remove()`.

If you are really stuck with arrays, you have to build a whole new Array, which size will be the size - 1 of your previous array, and then make a copy of the previous one into the new one. You should really consider using the first alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You will find it's easier to use a second datastructure for counting. Try this:

```
// Count each word
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String s: arrays) { // TODO rename "arrays" to "words" or something
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    int count = counts.get(s);
    if (count == null) {
        counts.put(s, 1);
    }
    else {
        counts.put(s, count + 1)
    }
}

// Sort and print
List<String> keys = counts.keySet();
Collections.sort(keys);
for (String key: keys) {
    System.out.println(key + ": " + counts[key]);
}
```